# Identify how many strings concatenated in google sheets / execl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to identify how many elements have been concatenated.

using `=LEN(CONCATENATE(Str1,Str2,Str3))` this gives the total length of whole string. I want 3 as output meaning 3 strings are concatenated, if among the 3 any one is empty then the output should be 2 and similarly if 2 are empty the o/p should be 1 and 0 when all are empty.

I couldn't find how to achieve this.

Any help on any formula or via apps script if we can achieve.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: to substract the empty values:

```
=counta(split(A1,",",1,1))-if(ifna(regexmatch(split(A1,",",1,1),",")),1,0)
```

Try with:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,",",1,1))
```

I assumed they were separated by commas, but you can change that

[image]

Comment: Working for 1 more than This is giving ```1``` even when all elements are empty, like for ``` , , ``` the output is ```1``` it should be ```0```

Comment: Hello @AliciaStone I updated with the option to substract th empty values

Comment: Thanks a ton @Martin, can you please explain what ```ifna(regexmatch(split(A1,",",1,1),","))``` does

Comment: Of course! When SPLIT is applied to ",,,,," (no value) since there's nothing to split it returns that same commas string and COUNTA would consider that value as 1. So with REGEXMATCH I've determined that if SPLIT returns at least one comma it would substract 1 from that previous "erroneous" value of 1, resulting in the correct count of 1-1= 0.